# can I specialize operator<<?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I want to specialize operator<< but this code is not compiling;

```
template<>

std::ostream& operator<< < my_type >( std::ostream& strm, my_type obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specialize a template, first you have to have a template declared.

In the case of a free `operator<<` you don't need a template; you can just overload it for your `my_type` class:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm, my_type obj );
```

If your object isn't trivial in size, you may want to consider passing via a const reference so that you don't copy it every time you stream it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm, const my_type& obj );
```

(Technically you can explicitly specialize an `operator<<`, but I don't think that this is what you want or need. In order to be able to use a template operator<< with the usual << syntax you need to make the template specialization deducible from one of the parameter types.

E.g.

```
// template op <<
template< class T >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, const MyTemplClass<T>& );

// specialization of above
template<>
std::ostream& operator<< <int>( std::ostream&, const MyTemplClass<int>& );
```

)

Comment: Charles please read my comment which I wrote for GMan's answer

Comment: @Davit Siradeghyan: If you have a template which is a catch all for *all* types (needless to say this is almost always a bad idea), then you can specialize it but it is still simpler to overload it for your particular types. Overload resolution will chose an exact match of a non-template function over a function template.

Comment: I'm with Charles, having a totally generic insertion operator seems really dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just overload?

```
// no template <>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm, my_type obj);
```

You only specialize when there exists a template *to* specialize.

<sub>Your parameter should probably be `const my_type&`, to avoid a needless copy.</sub>

Comment: Yes I know about overloading, I need to overload operator<< for a group of types, imagine that inside of operator body I'm checking types for some T1, T2 or t3, doing one thing for them and another for all other types

Comment: @Davit: How about instead of 'imagine', you post the bigger picture in he question? :) The more information we get, the better the answer. (In other words: post the problem, not the step.)

Comment: This is my code
template< typename T >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &strm, const T &e );

and I want to specialize operator<< for some T1, T2 and T3 types which are not POD types.